# Spark SQL 1.6.0 - massive memory usage for simple query

Tags: dataframe, hive, apache-spark-sql

I'm using Spark 1.6 on EMR 4.3 to query ~15TB of data belonging to a table in a hive metastore (backed by gzipped parquet files in S3). For my cluster I have a r3.8xlarge master node and 15 r3.8xlarge core nodes (3.6TB RAM, 9.6TB SSD).

The ~15TB data is contained in maybe 9 billion rows. Each row has ~15 columns that store strings of length 5-50, and one column which contains an array of ~30 strings, 10-20 characters each. There are only ~1 million unique strings stored in the array. All I'm trying to do is count the unique strings in the array column, but it seems I'm running out of memory as I keep getting: **OutOfMemoryError: unable to create new native thread** on the executors. The tasks fail due to the out of memory error, the executors get disabled, and then the job fails.

It works when I query 5-10TB of data. I must not understand correctly what gets stored in memory (which is what I'm trying to figure out). Btw, with the above cluster, I'm setting:

```
spark.executor.memory 30g
spark.executor.cores 5
spark.executor.instances 90 // 6 instances per r3.8xlarge host
```

I didn't think Spark SQL stored the intermediary tables in memory. Since there aren't more than 1M unique strings, I would think that the strings with their counts should easily fit in memory. Here's the query:

```
val initial_df = sqlContext.sql("select unique_strings_col from Table where timestamp_partition between '2016-09-20T07:00:00Z' and '2016-09-23T07:00:00Z'")
initial_df.registerTempTable("initial_table") // ~15TB compressed data to read in from S3

val unique_strings_df = sqlContext.sql("select posexplode(unique_strings_col) as (string_pos, string) from initial_table").select($"string_pos", $"string")
unique_strings_df.registerTempTable("unique_strings_table")  // ~70% initial data remaining at this point

val strings_count_df = sqlContext.sql("select string, count(*) as unique_string_count from unique_strings_table where string_pos < 21 group by string order by unique_string_count desc") // ~50% initial data remaining at this point
strings_count_df.write.parquet("s3://mybucket/counts/2016-09-20-2016-09-23")
```

The compressed parquet files are small (say 5mb each). It seems like they could be read one at a time, filtered, and stored with their counts. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

So it turns out that I need to have enough disk + memory space to store the initial RDD. If I do more up-front filtering in the initial RDD before creating the temp table, I'm able to run the query successfully. Yay!